# $scope vs var in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, variables

I've been using var and $scope.varname and both work fine in AngularJS. I was wondering if there was a difference between the two functionally, and what best practice was in which one to use?

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question... everything defined on the `scope` is a `property` of the `scope` thus exposed to the `html`, and local `vars` in the `controller` are not exposed and are their own `objects`.

Comment: @furier perfect. Exactly the clarification I was looking for.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes! `$scope` variables bind to the view where as `var` does not and is local to the function it was declared in!

```
var x = 3;
$scope.y = 3;

{{x}} - undefined
{{y}} - 3
```

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies a lot. So any variables I'm using strictly for logic in the JS should be `var` and any variables that need to be open to the front-end should be in $scope?

Comment: @itamar -- pretty much, yep

Comment: GOOD TO KNOW. I've been using `$scope` on *all* my variables. tired of seeing `$scope` everywhere! Finally decided to see if I need it or if I can just use var. Plus, this will help distinguish in the code which variables effect the view! :D

Comment: @Shane - a while later, I can say there def is. The more $scope variables you have, the more has to be checked when the digest cycle runs. So if it's not used in the UI, don't keep it as a $scope variable.

Comment: $scope is "like" global variables?

Comment: @MáximaAlekz No It's not like global variable but you can make it global as well as in the accessible scope. Read the furier's comment on top after reading this answer.

Comment: What is the significance of `$` in the variables ? What are some with `$` and some without and some even `$$` ?

Answer (score 8):

The technical implications of using `var` and `$scope` have been described by @tymeJV and others.  I think the next logical question answer is:  *When do I use either?*

TL;DR - if you do not use a variable in a view (e.g. `{{myVar}}` ), use `var`.

The reason is two fold:

1. **Encapsulation** - hide state that is not necessary to the view.  This will prevent unintended modifications of the variable.
2. **Performance** (prevent extra digest cycles) - Angular performs "dirty state" checking on variables.  Modifying a variable that's not used in the view may cause extra digest cycles unnecessarily.  In an application with a couple of `ng-repeat`s and a bunch of watches, this can have a huge impact.

Answer (score 7):

1 - $scope, is the **glue** between your controller and your view/model , when you are defining a variable/function to the $scope of a controller, your whole view , which this controller controls it ! , can see that variable/function . Where a pure variable just works in that controller , not even the view of that controller!

2- Every thing that has been defined to the $scope , is manupulatable from the outside of the controller , throughout the **Directives** , **Services** , **your html view** ... , while a pure variable is NOT;

Answer (score 2):

Simply spoken - all variables you define on $scope, e.g. in your controller,  are available in your html markup. in case you need a variable just inside your js functions, you can declare it with var, they are only locally available. Same with functions.

Answer (score 0):

$scope bind value to the view and var is the local variable to the application.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.