# Angularjs input search field focus event?

Tags: angularjs

Trying to capture the focus or click event of a user returning to a search field.

```
<form name="searchUser">
    <input type="search" placeHolder="Username to find" ng-model="username" ng-focus="focusSet()">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" ng-click="search(username)" />
</form>
```

When someone click on the text(search) field I want to start a timer. The timer works for the initial page refresh but I cant get it to work for ng-focus or ng-click. So I degenerated to a simple focusSet function that just writes a line to the console. But it never writes the line on focus. Also tried this with click.

Why does angular not respond to the focus event?

```
var focusSet = function(){
  $log.info("Got Focus");
  $scope.focusSet = "now you see me";

};
```

here is my plunker if you want to see the whole thing http://plnkr.co/edit/zmWVWJrigRYkQk5jS5HU?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$scope.focusSet = function(){
  $log.info("Got Focus");
  // $scope.focusSet = "now you see me";
};
```

Comment: I tried this. Obviously you cant set a scope.focusSet inside of scope.focusSet function, but after updating the variable it worked. Im new to angular, can you explain why this worked vs my implementation?

Comment: This kind of helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287954/scope-vs-var-in-angularjs, but im still a little fuzzy on how it relates to var functions.

Comment: any attribute name you define in ng-* such as ng-model, ng-click, ng-focus belongs to the controller scope, that's why you have to declare `$scope.focusSet`