# angularjs: not able to pass a variable value from controller to view

Tags: angularjs

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('myApp.home', [])

        .factory('myService', function($http) {
            return {
                getInfo: function() {
                    // return something
                }
            };
        })

        .controller('HomeController', function($scope, $routeParams, myService) {
                var my = this;      
                var sid;

                myService.getInfo().success(function(data) {

                    my.id   = data.id;
                    //sid= my.id;
                });

                //my.id     = sid;
        });
})();
```

I'm trying to access the variable id in my view. But I'm not able to do so. I'm getting an undefined variable error.

I even tried to declare a variable `sid` globally so that it can be accessed from everywhere and I tried assigning value to it as well but that effort also didn't bring up any results.

My services are working fine and they are returning data. I'm trying to use the `id` in my view but don't know where I messed it up.
Any help?

**EDIT**

And my HTML is like this:

```
<div data-id="my.id"></div>
```

Comment: where is vm.id in controller? It should rather by $scope.id = my.id and in html <div>{{id}}</div>

Comment: I want to pass it as a data attribute. @Rahul Arora

Comment: <div data-id="{{id}}"></div> and $scope.id = my.id

Comment: Did you declare controller like this `ng-controller='HomeController as vm'`?

Comment: hmm, we might need more infor of your html :\

Comment: I haved added full html. @Owen Hsieh

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in your view you have to bind it to a scope e.g. `$scope.id` - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287954/scope-vs-var-in-angularjs) link for reference.

Comment: I tried this. Even when I use $scope, sometimes it works and most of time, it returns undefined. @SeRu

Comment: can you show the code where you are trying it with $scope?

Comment: AngularJS only binds that data to the template that is linked with $scope in the controller

Comment: You dont call your controller in the html. try `HomeController.id` instead of `vm.id`

Answer (score 0):

use `controllerAs : vm` then you can access `vm.id` in your view.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="HomeController as vm">
     <div data-id="vm.id">{{vm.id}}</div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('HomeController', function () {
    var vm = this;
    vm.id = "someValue";    
});
```

for more info [read this](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/)

Answer (score 0):

Below is your `html`, how it should be.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="HomeController as home">
     <div data-id="home.id">{{home.id}}</div>
</div>
```

Below is how your `controller` part.

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('HomeController', function () {
    this.id = "someValue";    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grdmLfxt/

Comment: Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [ngController, uibTabset (module: ui.bootstrap.tabs)] asking for new/isolated scope on: <div active="active" ng-controller="HomeController as vm"> @Thalaivar

Comment: @AmeliaEarheart: very difficult to say from here, can you share your complete html part... and btw instead of vm.id you can also use $scope.id

Comment: I haved added full html.  @Thalaivar

Answer (score 0):

small change in javascript code and html. try this.

*Javascript*

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('myApp.home', [])

        .factory('myService', function($http) {
            return {
                getInfo: function() {
                    // return something
                }
            };
        })

        .controller('HomeController', function($scope, $routeParams, myService) {
                var my = this;      
                var sid;

                myService.getInfo().success(function(data) {

                    $scope.id   = data.id;  // changed from my.id to $scope.id
                    //sid= my.id;
                });

                //my.id     = sid;
        });
})();
```

*HTML*

```
<div data-id="id"></div>
```