# Ionic app does not print $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

I have an ionic app which uses angularjs. Inside the angular controller I am not able to print `$scope` with `console.log($scope)`. However I am able to access variables likes `$scope.var`.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['starter.services','ngCordova'])
.controller('SettingCtrl', function($scope){
   console.log('SettingCtrl ');
   console.log($scope);
   console.log('end');
}
```

The output is

```
1     453753   log      SettingCtrl 
2     453760   log      end
```

It ignores the line referencing to $scope entirely.
What am i missing here?

Update: 
I modified and assigned some value to $scope like

```
console.log('SettingCtrl ');
$scope.var = 1;
console.log($scope.var);
console.dir($scope);
console.log('end');
```

And the output for this

```
1     332968   log      SettingCtrl  
2     332970   log      1
3     332972   log      end
```

Comment: what is console.dir?

Comment: its a way of printing objects

Comment: Do you even know what scope is?

It's like you are trying to print var. You need to give it a value if you expect it to print something, this way you are just declaring it

Please read 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287954/scope-vs-var-in-angularjs

Comment: shouldnt it print a blank line in case there is no value for $scope

Comment: @avck it will print, just double check

Comment: The thing you do here is just injecting scope into a function, making the function ready to use it in its body

Comment: @Marko I have injected it and I wanted to do 2 way data binding. In my view I have a button which calls a function defined in scope. inside the function i am not able to access values of the model, its coming as blank, therefore I am printing the scope to debug.

Comment: ok so, based on the edit, it prints 1, what is the issue then? by the way don't name your scope var

Comment: how are you printing the scope in view? You should do it like $scope.test = 1 and then in associated html you do{{test}} and it will display 1 on web page

Comment: I want the entire $scope object to be printed

Answer (score 0):

In a browser inspector this will work but if you're watching the logs on your terminal after launching a

`$ ionic run`

then it might ignore any `console.dir`. To workaround this issue you can `console.log(JSON.stringify(object))` but I am not sure it would work on the `$scope` object because it might not be stringifiable due to circular references