# Is there are relation between variables "var x" and scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS to make mobile application with onsen and monaca
in my controller I need to use many variables to make some operation and I don't need to display it so according to this post 
[$scope vs var in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287954/scope-vs-var-in-angularjs) 
I defined my controller in this way

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('pdfPlanCtrl',['$scope',function($scope) {
    var newHeight;
    var newWidth;
    function drawOldLines(pointBeginX, pointBeginY, pointEndX, pointEndY, color){
           ---- some code --------
           console.log('drawOldLines scope id '+$scope.$id);
           console.log('newWidth= '+newWidth);
    }
}]);
```

In my controller as I said above I used this variables for some calculation operations by calling the function drawOldLines

I call this function from two positions
when some one touch canvas and when some one click on button

When some one touch canvas I get this result in log:

```
drawOldLines scope id  13
newWidth = 160
```

And when I click on the button I get

```
drawOldLines scope id  22
newWidth = undefined
```

How can I newWidth value in two cases? Or maybe help me to understand what the relation is between var variables and scopes?

**UPDATED**: I added the function inside my controller

Comment: I see some confusion here-- there is no reason that `newHeight`/`newWidth` should be available in `drawOldLines`, as they are encapsulated in the function scope of your `pdfPlanCtrl` (unless `drawOldLines` is defined in the controller).  Basically, variables are local only to the JS scope where they are defined (as well as nested scopes).  However, if you were to expose the values as properties of the Angular `$scope` they would be available for interpolation in your templates/views.

Comment: you are correct the function  is part from my controller

Comment: Can you please provide some demo on fiddle to reproduce the problem. Seem's that there are some mistake in you outer code.

Comment: the problem is solved when I changed the varibale declearation type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I changed the code from

```
var newHeight;
var newWidth;
```

to

```
$rootScope.newHeight;
$rootScope.newWidth;
```

the problem is solved