# Is it considered a bad practice to modify a scope variable multiple times in a row?

Tags: angularjs

For example, we have a code like this:

```
function(result) {
 $scope.data = result.data;
 $scope.data[0] = someData;
 $scope.data.forEach(...some more changes...)
}
```

Will modifying the scope variable would be slower than modifying a temp common variable, like in the code below?

```
function(result) {
 var data = result.data;
 data[0] = someData;
 data.forEach(...some more changes...)
 $scope.data = data;
}
```

Comment: Technically, it's the same thing (apart from wastes from creating a local variable, which in any case are insignificant), as you operate on the same object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$scope vs var in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287954/scope-vs-var-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about triggering spurious temporary state changes, that is not going to happen. The state changes are only applied between "ticks" of your event loop. So the first example is fine.

Style-wise, I would probably use a local variable if I refer to some nested object more than once.

Also not that the final `$scope.data = data` is redundant, because you did not assign `data` to anything new: It is still pointing to the same object it was in the beginning, that one is still attached to the scope and any modifications to its state will be visible in the scope as well.

Answer (score 1):

Same only but `$scope` watch by angularjs so watches times-count(*ex. 5 times*) increase while change the value like here `$scope.data[0] = someData;`.

Comment: Are you sure the watch will trigger by the assignment itself? Won't that be deferred until the method returns (so that five assignments will still only trigger one update)?

Comment: I said example count five times. And $scope.data[0] = someData; he is assign new data so watch will trigger right.